# Good book for introduction to Tarski-Grothendieck set theory?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

I'm looking for an introductory book on Tarski-Grothendieck (TG) set theory. The emphasis should be on TG, not on large cardinals, or long detailed comparisons between TG and other theories.

Does anyone know of such a book?

Answer (score 0):

Try the introductory chapter of P.M. Cohn's Universal Algebra.

Comment: Thanks. More broadly, would you recommend Cohn's Universal Algebra for an introduction to universal algebra? I've had little exposure to that area but I'd like to learn more.